# Update my old Java app to the latest version in android studio

Tags: android

A few years ago I coded an application in Java language as an amateur in Android Studio. But now I have to upgrade my application to the latest SDK. But Android Studio now only continues with Kotlin. I get a lot of errors when I open my application. I get separate errors when updating Gradle files and more when I convert to Kotlin.
What can I do, please give me your opinion.

Comment: Android Studio still provides a way to work with Java if you select Views Activity when building a new app/activity. Please share the error details for further debugging https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Java is still fully supported by Android and Android Studio.  You can even call Java from Kotlin code or vice versa.  What your actual problem are you'd need to post a lot more info for us to help.  Most likely the problems are due to changes in the gradle plugin and the SDK itself, but we'd nee the code and the errors to help those.